# Equivalent of -viewDidAppear for CCLayer?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, uikit

**Question:**
In the realm of cocos2d for iPhone, what's the equivalent of UIKit's -viewDidAppear callback for CCLayer?

*And if no equivalent exists (*as seems to be the case in the docs*), what's your recommended way knowing when a CCLayer has been rendered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are these two methods which are quite similar to

```
- (void)onEnter;
- (void)onEnterTransitionDidFinish;
```

Comment: This seems like what I'm looking for. I'll test it out later to see if it works. Thanks.

Comment: I believe these methods are for CCScenes, not CCLayers, as asked by the user. See my answer for more detailed discussion of CCLayer.

Answer (score 2):

Well, a CCLayer is rendered, usually, when it is created and you add sprites to it. You should do all this up front before the game play begins. Then you can move the layer around and animate its objects without worrying about "when" it will be finished rendering (usually).

Scenes are a different matter. A scene is what sets up the layers and creates them, loads images, sprites, etc, and tha can take a bit. For that you have a few options. One effective option is the the `onEnter` and `onExit` family of methods. However, another really good way is to simply have an intermediate scene, such as a mostly empty, lean Loading CCScene that you load, and then that scene loads the big scene you are trying to load. When you do this, you are freeing up old memory before adding new memory.

It really depends on what you are trying to accomplish with your equivalent of viewDidAppear.

Comment: Thanks andrewx for this answer. I did ultimately chose another answer since it seemed more immediately useful to my problem. Much appreciated though.

Comment: Hi Eric -- as noted in my answer, the onEnter technique mentioned in the other answer I don't think applies to CCLayers, mentioned in your question. Only scenes. It's been a while since I've done some Cocos programming however, so maybe that has changed (I don't think it has).